# Running a Flask app on nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I don't know exactly what I am doing but I am experimenting with running Flask on nginx. I am boiling it down to the simple bit of code below. First I have a test app in Flask like this:

```
 from flask import Flask, render_template

 app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='client', template_folder='client/html')

 def show_home_page():
    return render_template("home.html")

 @app.route('/')
 def server():
    return show_home_page()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True)
```

If I run python app.py I can go to http://localhost:5000 and see the "Hello World". Next I read that I need to run uwsgi but its not clear what params I need to pass to it. I tried different things like:

```
 uwsgi -s /tmp/app.sock --manage-script-name --mount ./=app:app
```

I also noted that I need to set my nginx conf file to match, but I am stuck on that as well (I just get a welcome from nginx on port 5000) and it doesnt seem to link with my Flask app. I googled around a bit but nothing has clicked yet.

```
server {
    listen       5000;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using an nginx reverse proxy? Then you don't want nginx **and** flask on 5000

Comment: Are you able to access the site directly through uwsgi? It may be easier to verify that's working before sending the connection through nginx.

Comment: How do i verify that I can access through uwsgi?

Comment: I'm no uwsgi expert but the way I've used it in the past is by deploying it on an http port. You don't need to make that port publically accesible since you're eventually planning to deploy behind nginx, but that means you could specify that port in the browser. It looks like that's not quite the route you're going down right now but I guess I'm curious why that is. It might help to take a look at the quick start docs if you haven't yet: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html . They give a pretty straightforward example that seems to match what you're after.

Comment: I get errors for a lot of documentation I see, for instance for the one above:
uwsgi --http-socket :9090 --wsgi-file app.py 
uwsgi: unrecognized option `--wsgi-file'
getopt_long() error

Comment: Have you installed the python uwsgi plugin? You can get it using `pip install uwsgi`.

Comment: You will need to setup `uwsgi_pass` in your nginx config before nginx will know to pass the calls onto you uwsgi instance http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Nginx.html

Comment: What @Bartlett said, you need to config nginx to pass requests to uwsgim which you are not doing

Answer (score 1):

You can use refer this for Flask with Nginx and uWSGI: 
[Python flask with Nginx and uWSGI](https://github.com/source-nerd/Python-flask-with-uwsgi-and-nginx)